# Submit same forms with two buttons and send thank you mail only on the second submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having the issue on submitting the same form with two submit buttons. I am submitting the form for the first time with ajax submission and on the second time I want to submit the whole form but  when I send the form the thank you mail hits two times . I want to send the thank you mail only on the second submit button and not on the first button. I have the button type ="button" ,

Here is my form code:-

```
<form name="basicform" id="basicform" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/forms/callback/callback_process.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  ?>" name="source" id="source" />
        <input type="hidden" value="submited" name="basicform"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_name" id="form_name" value="Header Contact Form" class="basicformname" >
          <div id="sf1" class="frm">
            <fieldset>
              <!--<legend>Take a step for a Good health.</legend>-->
              <div class="wor-alert"><p class="text-center fill-fields">Please Fill All This Fields*</p></div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon"><i class="travcure-icon travcure-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="uname" name="uname" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="nameerr" id="unameerr"><?php echo @$_SESSION['unameerr'] ? $_SESSION['unameerr']:''; unset($_SESSION['unameerr']); ?></span>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon"><i class="travcure-icon travcure-envelope"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="uemail" name="uemail" class="form-control" autocomplete="on">
                  <span class="emailerr"  id="uemailerr"><?php echo @$_SESSION['uemailerr'] ? $_SESSION['uemailerr']:''; unset($_SESSION['uemailer']); ?></span>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" id="uphone" name="uphone" class="uphone form-control" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="phoneerr"  id="uphoneerr"><?php echo @$_SESSION['uphoneerr'] ? $_SESSION['uphoneerr']:''; unset($_SESSION['uphoneerr']); ?></span>
                  <input type="hidden" class="uphonefull" name="uphonefull">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon"><i class="travcure-icon travcure-user-md"></i></span>
                   <span class="plain-select">
                     <select name="utreatments" data-style="btn-primary" id="utreatments" class="form-control selectpicker">
                      <option value="">Select Treatment</option>
                      <option value="Alternative Treatment">Alternative Treatment</option>
                      <option value="2">Treatment Two</option>
                      <option value="3">Treatment Three</option>
                      <option value="4">Treatment Four</option>
                      <option value="5">Treatment Five</option>
                    </select>
                  </span>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>


              <div class=" text-center">

                  <button class="btn open1" type="button" id="head-frm-btn">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button> 

              </div>

            </fieldset>
          </div>

          <div id="sf2" class="frm" style="display: none;">
            <fieldset>
              <!--<legend>What treatment are you looking for?</legend>-->

              <div class="form-group">
                 <span class="plain-select">
                  <select name="ucity" id="ucity" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                    <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                    <option value="Banglore">Banglore</option>
                    <option value="Nagpur">Nagpur</option>
                    <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
                  </select>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <span class="plain-select">
                  <select name="uhospital" id="uhospital" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Hospital</option>
                    <option value="Hospital One">Hospital One</option>
                    <option value="Hospital Two">Hospital Two</option>
                    <option value="Hospital Three">Hospital Three</option>
                    <option value="Hospital Four">Hospital Four</option>
                    <option value="Hospital Five">Hospital Five</option>
                  </select>
                </span>
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>



              <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>

              <div class=" text-center">

                  <button class="btn back2" type="button"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button> 
                  <button class="btn open2" type="button" id="head-frm-btn-two">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button> 

              </div>

            </fieldset>
          </div>

          <div id="sf3" class="frm" style="display: none;">
            <fieldset>
              <!--<legend>Almost done</legend>-->

              <div class="waittext">
                  <p>Our customer care executive will get in contact with you soon. Please bear with us.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px;clear: both;"></div>

              <div class=" text-center">

                  <button class="btn back3" type="button"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Back</button> 
                  <input class="btn open3" value="Submit" type="submit" name="head_form_submit"> 


              </div>

            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I submit this form using ajax for the first submit button and then on the second button I send the whole information  but I want to send the thank you mail on the second button and not on the ajax submission of the button. I want to get th email of both the forms but i want to send the thank you mail only on the second submit button.

Comment: type='button' when submitted, sends the x/y coordinates of where the mouse was clicked. Therefore the is no useful information set that the submit routine can handle. Changing the type='submit' allows the browser to show a button and when submitted sends a name/value pair. This information can be using by the submission process to check which button was clicked and then act accordingly.

Comment: I am sending the first form with ajax that is why I am using type="button" but when I am using type ="submit" it sends the form completely. I am using a multilevel form as you can see in the code I want users "name",''email","phone number","treatment" on the first submission of the form and on the second submit I want the city and the hospital with the previous information.

Answer (score 2):

you can use two submit buttons

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit form</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_and_send_email">Submit and Send Email</button>
```

in php you can access the post like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //submit only
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit_and_send_email']))
    {
        //submit and send email
    }
?>
```

Comment: I know this I want to access on the button type="button" when i press this button the form is submitted with ajax . and on the second submit the button type is submit button.

Comment: @PranaySute The Tamil's answer is pretty correct: it shows you how to organize your PHP script (called both when 1st and 2nd buttons are clicked) to make exactly what you said you want. What else is not clear to you?

Comment: Well, anyways I find out the solution myself. Thanks !